# Magento security issue

Tags: php, security, magento

I am using a magento for my site. I am facing the some problem with it. After some time a code gets added in the header of the index files. and my site stops working. When I remove that error like (encrypted) code again site works well.

Is there any way to avoid such code injections? I searched on the net but have not got the proper solution.

Comment: do you have any upload forms on your site? what version of php are you using? are you hosting the site on shared hosting?

Comment: Why do you think it is magento issue, not an issue made by a developer who had built your site?

Comment: nop, no any upload forms. PHP 5.2.7.yes there is a shared hosting.

Comment: Looks like the server has been compromised. Report this to your hosting company.

Comment: @zerkms : i am the developer of that site. I checked in coding also but not found anything suspicious

Comment: @user1713694: so what kind of help are you expecting? Security is not an easy area, it cannot be explained in a single question answer.

Comment: @Dr. Dan: can i made only magento secure.

Comment: @zerkms : i am just asking can we made some thing to magento store, so that it will help to keep it secure.

Comment: @user1713694: it is well written and secured.

Comment: @zerkms: yes it is well secured. Thanks for urgent replys.

Comment: If the server has been compromised, and it probably has - yes, you can do something to make magento store secure. Move it to another server.

Comment: @user1713694 If the  attacker somehow adds a payload to all the php files you can't really secure Magento in any way. Resolve the attack vector or move it to another server

Comment: it's probably this [CVE-2012-2311](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-2311/) and this [CVE-2012-1823](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-1823/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `/var` and `/media` directories need to be writeable during normal operation, remove write privileges for the PHP user for all other dirs and files.  This makes injection attacks much harder.

This will interfere with updates applied via the Connect Manager, but I don't like to use that on live sites anyway.  I prefer to apply updates on a local or staging copy, test, then upload via FTP or version control which does have write privileges.